# Capturing a handlebars template as a string

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template that I'd like to capture its output as a string that I can store on a model.  For example:

I'm using Ember Rails, so I don't have the script tag

in app/assets/javascripts/templates/person_as_xml.handlebars

```
<person>
  <name>{{name}}</name>
  <children>
  {{#each children}}
    <kid><name>{{name}}</name></kid>
  {{/each}}
  </children>
</person>
```

Then I want to, perhaps in an action:

```
actions: {
  save: function(person){
    person.xml_representation = Handlebars.render_template("person_as_xml.handlebars", person);
    person.save();
  }
}
```

Obviouisly I made up the syntax for render_template, but that's essentially what I want to do.  How can I do it?

Comment: A couple questions here... are you trying to get the output of the template at the current time it is being rendered.  What I mean by that is when the values for Name, and each children have been filled in and are populated in your XML.

If so... why not just take the `this.$().html()` of your view, and then you will have the string format.  It sounds like you won't be displaying this XML in the DOM, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var source = "<person><name>{{name}}</name><children>{{#each children}}<kid><name>{{name}}</name></kid>{{/each}}</children></person>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "name": "Alan", "children": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var result = template(data);
```

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.  This will output:

```
<person>
  <name>
    Alan
  </name>
  <children>
    <kid>
      <name>
        Jimmy
      </name>
    </kid>
    <kid>
      <name>Sally</name>
    </kid>
  </children>
</person>
```

I haven't convered getting your HBS file into this string, but I assume you can figure out a method to do that that makes sense in your application.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  Thank you for answering!